# Laravel - Turn part of a function into a queued statement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, task-queue

I want to queue part of a function within my controller, mainly because it accesses a 3rd party API and calculates certain information from said request. I also want to do this to increase my knowledge of queues!

The code which I want queueing is:

The only variables that will need pushing with this `if statement` is `$postcode` and `$clinic ID` (which is figured out above the statement).

```
if($clinic->postcode != $postcode)
    {

     $client = new Client([ 'base_uri' => 'https://api.postcodes.io/','timeout' => 2.0, 'verify' => false ]);
     $response = $client->get('postcodes/'.$postcode)->getBody();

     $input = json_decode($response);

     $clinic->latitude   = $input->result->latitude;
     $clinic->longitude  = $input->result->longitude;
     $clinic->save();
}
```

So far I have created the `queue` table and migrated it.

I then ran the command: `php artisan make:job GetClinicLatAndLongPoints --queued`

My question is, how can I put this function inside the `GetClinicLatAndLongPoints` including passing the two variables over to do so?

I have so far:

```
public function handle(Clinic $clinic, $postcode)
    {

    }
```

But I'm unsure how to lay things out! Any guidance would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: what version of laravel are you using, you tagged both! lol

Comment: Oops, sorry! I've removed Laravel 4. I am using the latest of Laravel 5.1.*!

Comment: Did you try copy pasting it in your handle function? Also make sure your queue is running (`php artisan queue:listen`)

Comment: Yes, but I am unsure how to pass over the necessary variables for the `if statement` to correctly work.

Comment: I think L5 supports object serialization of an Eloquent Model instance.. Just send the model along and see what happens ;)

Comment: Seeing some [examples](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues) in the usercontroller, it must be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an instance of your `Clinic` model and the postal code to the constructor of your job, which may look along the lines of

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Clinic;
use App\Jobs\Job;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class GetClinicLatAndLongPoints extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    private $clinic;
    private $postcode;

    public function __construct(Clinic $clinic, $postcode)
    {
        $this->clinic = $clinic; // Laravel will automatically deserialize the model instance
        $this->postcode = $postcode;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $coordinates = $this->getCoordinates($this->postcode);

        if (! is_null($coordinates)) {
            // You may want to add error handling
            $this->clinic->latitude   = $coordinates['latitude'];
            $this->clinic->longitude  = $coordinates['longitude'];
            $this->clinic->save();
        }
    }

    private function getCoordinates($postcode)
    {
        $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://api.postcodes.io/','timeout' => 2.0, 'verify' => false]);
        $response = json_decode($client->get('postcodes/'.$postcode)->getBody()->getContents());
        if (! $response || json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            return null;
        }
        if ($response->status == 200 &&
            isset($response->result->latitude) &&
            isset($response->result->longitude)) {
            return [
                'latitude' => $response->result->latitude,
                'longitude' => $response->result->longitude
            ];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In your controller you dispatch your job

```
if ($clinic->postcode != $postcode) {
    $this->dispatch(new GetClinicLatAndLongPoints($clinic, $postcode));
}
```

*On a side note: although Laravel comes with the database queue driver using it in production is not a very good idea. Better make use of one of the [job queues](http://queues.io) i.e. [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/).*

Comment: What a fantastic answer and extremely clear! Thank you very much for your help @peterm! As an addition to your answer, I had to add `use App\Jobs\GetClinicLatAndLongPoints;` to the Controller.

The only issue I'm currently experiencing now is the following error within the `GetClinicLatAndLongPoints` script - `"FatalErrorException in GetClinicLatAndLongPoints.php line 13: Class 'App\Jobs\Job' not found"`. The GetClinicLat... isn't inside a 'Job' folder, per say, just the `Jobs` folder. I'm unsure why this is?

Comment: It turns out that I didn't have the default `Job.php` that should come with Laravel! Copying that over makes everything work correctly. Many thanks again.